# How to I launch an on-screen keyboard from my application on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

I know there is an on-screen keyboard which you can access on Mac OSX, however I need to add a toolbar button to launch it from within my application.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch KeyboardViewerServer.app in whatever way your language does that (you do not say which)

From Terminal:

```
open -a KeyboardViewerServer
```

I found it in /System/Library/Components/KeyboardViewer.component/Contents/SharedSupport/KeyboardViewerServer.app

If you have problems with it on Leopard, see also

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1257002&tstart=50

Comment: Cool, this should go on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269500/hidden-features-of-the-mac-os-x-environment.